# scale in rendition key must match passed in scale in the image description

Tags: ios, iphone

Native app on iOS, I'm getting crash due to this reason:

> scale in rendition key must match passed in scale in the image
>   description

App works fine on simulator, but on device it crashes when try to open a modal screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. In my case, the problem is that I had a `UIButton` with an image that had a scale other than 1.0. When the user tapped the button, the app crashed with that same reason.

It turns out that the iOS 13 beta is not correctly creating the highlighted version of the image that gets displayed when the user taps the button. I created my own highlighted version of the image, with the same scale as the original, and it worked fine.

```
- (void)updateButtonImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGFloat heightScale = image.size.height / self.edgeLength;
    CGFloat widthScale = image.size.width / self.edgeLength;
    CGFloat scale = MIN(heightScale, widthScale);
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) scale:scale]
          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // iOS 13 beta does not properly create the highlighted image for a scaled image. This caused the
    // app to crash when the user tapped the image. For now, we'll work around this by creating our
    // own highlighted image and explicitly setting it on this button.
    // https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/6961937
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.highlightedImage) scale:scale]
          forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

Comment: I discovered that, it seems any scale with floating point will cause the crash, for instance if you use 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 as scale, it works fine, but something like 2.6 does not!